# Test 2 Boolean Arrays

Tags: arrays, r, boolean

I have 2 identical length logical arrays. Im wondering if its possible to output a third array that is the result of if either one is true. I can do this with a for loop, but it seems like there should be an easier way. Any help would be appreciated. Below is what I use now:

```
High <- abs(Op - Hi) > testSize
Low <- abs(Op - Lo) > testSize
for (i in 1:length(High)) {
  if (High[i] == TRUE){
    X[i] <- TRUE
  } else if (Low[i] == TRUE){
    X[i] <- TRUE
  } else {
    X[i] <- FALSE
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `High`? What is `Low`? Can you please add more detail to make this an [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Low` and `High` are logical vectors,  simply or them together

```
X = Low | High
```

For example

```
> a=c(T,F,T,F)
> b=c(T,T,F,F)
> a|b
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Its so depressing that thats the answer compared to what I tried. Thanks for your help!